# Parse.com Mixed Content Error

Tags: https, parse-platform, pffile, mixed-content

I'm creating a web application using parse and have found that in order for a user to authenticate I need to make all requests using HTTPS. I'm able to switch this over and get it to work correctly, but when I do I get all kinds of mixed content errors because I'm retrieving PFFile objects which only return a non-secure URL.

This wouldn't even be a huge concern with Chrome or Safari but of course IE needs to present a message to the user and block all this content. Are there any potential work arounds? Why can't parse just put a setting in the app to enable files to be served from a secure url? This seems completely ridiculous. How do people get around this? Are you completely avoiding the use of PFFile?

Comment: I'm really starting to get sick of Parse adding new features when they have major issues existing that aren't being addressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace http:// with https://s3.amazonaws.com/.

So if you start with this:

`http://files.parsetfss.com/b05e3211-bf8b-.../tfss-fa825f28-e541-...-jpg`

The final url will look something like this:

`https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.parsetfss.com/b05e3211-bf8b-.../tfss-fa825f28-e541-...-jpg`

Comment: Source : http://hackingtheimpossible.com/quick-tip-serve-parse-files-via-https/

Parse have acknowledged that they don't serve files via HTTPS, so this is the only solution.
https://parse.com/questions/saving-loading-files-with-ssl

Comment: Thanks this definitely fixed it!